# How to use cookies to redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use cookies to redirect from main page to intro page, then go back from intro page to main page ?
And how to set cookies to allow people once ever 24h to see intro page instead of everytime loading a main page ?

Comment: Yes ..it is possible.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I'm aware that it is possible, but how can I do this. I'd like to learn something from javascript cause I'm not good at it. Would you mind to help me ?

Comment: first show what you have tried............

Comment: see this.It may help You:https://www.perlscriptsjavascripts.com/js/cookie_redirect.html

Comment: Okay thank you i'll try this, maybe this is going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For redirecting to another URL you should use window.location, not cookies

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

See e.g. [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery)

To set cookie you can use e.g.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp for more info

Comment: But the point is that i don't want to load this intro page everytime people load the main page, is it still possible to do with this ?

Comment: You can use `document.referrer` to define the URL where the user come to your page from.

Comment: I have shown you the tools. I hope you can realize how to use them to solve your problem.

Comment: I'll try my best, thank you and Will give you a feedback of what I'll try to do

Comment: Ok so I made this work with cookies. When I enter this intro page it will redirect me to my main page if cookies are set if not then you can see intro page.
But I can't handle this window.location.replace . I put this in my html:
<script> `function changesite()
            {
                window.location.replace("http://url/intro/index.html");
            }
            setTimeout("changesite();", 0);`
after this the rest of the code for cookies </script> But it doesn't replace my main url to the one I want :/

Comment: I don't know why you use `setTimeout` but you use it incorrectly. The correct usage is `setTimeout(changesite, 0)`

Comment: Because I want it to redirect immediately after someone get on the website

Comment: Is this not a good way to do this ? and in which file i should add window.location.replace ? in the same file where I put cookie script (means in intro.html) or into index_front.html (which is main website template file) ?

Comment: You can simply use `changesite()`

Comment: damn I still dont get it, When I put this function changesite into index_front.html it loops throu intro and main site.